# Flutter Unable to create directory (OS Error: Read-only file system)

Tags: flutter

I was following - how to create directory from https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html

```
new Directory('dir/subdir').create(recursive: true)
  // The created directory is returned as a Future.
  .then((Directory directory) {
    print(directory.path);
});
```

This is the error I am getting:

> FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'dir' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)

I have enabled `Storage(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)` permission. 
(Android device)

What am I missing?

Comment: Use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider to get valid paths where you can read/write files.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks. Flutter Docs are slightly confusing.

Comment: Reading the docs I get that mostly all of them work only for Android and iOS. Is there a valid directory that could work for linux?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Got it (Using path_provider plugin to get correct path)

```
Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

new Directory(appDocDirectory.path+'/'+'dir').create(recursive: true)
// The created directory is returned as a Future.
    .then((Directory directory) {
  print('Path of New Dir: '+directory.path);
});
```

Comment: Is there a sycnhronous version of `Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`?

Answer (score 6):

Update : New Flutter plugin **permission_handler** have taken care below thing so change your plugin to **permission_handler**

If you are testing in Android Oreo and want to write file in external storage then you need to ask WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

According to "https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp"

> If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only
>   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the system immediately grants that privilege
>   without prompting the user.

[Permission Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/permission) ask only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission by `Permission.requestPermissions([PermissionName.Storage])`;
so You need to ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

You can use my repo for asking WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in pubspec.yaml:

```
permission:
    git:
    url: https://github.com/kamlesh9070/permission
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have given the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission but still not able to create the directory,

you can try **manually uninstalling** the Flutter App from the device,

and rerun it.

NOTE: make sure after the installation, allow the **storage permission** from the app settings.

It works for me after struggling for hours (I don't know why this solution works)

Answer (score 0):

this might be late as an answer, permission handler did not solve the issue, the code below anyhow did

```
  Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var dbLocation = '${appDocDirectory.path}/$_dbName';

  _db = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(dbLocation,
               version: 1, mode: DatabaseMode.create);
```

for whoever is still struggling with the solutions supplied above

the mode: DatabaseMode.create does not recreate the Db upon restart, rebuild or debug restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error from Isar library.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'; 
final isar = await Isar.open([
        schemas..,
      ], name: 'test_instance', directory: (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path,);
```

This solves the problem.
You should have path_provider library and required permissions from user.

Answer (score 0):

had this problem on my WSL2 machine. Even git operations were returning this error. Had to shutdown WSL from Powershell with `wsl --shutdown` and launch it again. Seems like it was an I/O bug and nothing to do with Flutter