# Flutter: How to Convert bytes to a File in order to upload the file to Firestore

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to watermark an image with the text in flutter and then need to upload that watermarked Image on the Firestore. When I try to watermark and store the bytes to a File I am getting an error.

`File: '����`

Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you!

Here is the code part.

```
  _originalImage = ui.decodeImage(croppedFile.readAsBytesSync());
  ui.drawString(_originalImage, ui.arial_24, 100, 120, 'Hello World');
    // Store the watermarked image to a File
   List<int> resImage = ui.encodeJpg(_originalImage);
   print(resImage);
    setState((){
      _watermarkedImage = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List.fromList(wmImage));
      print(_watermarkedImage);
    });
  imageFile = _watermarkedImage;
```

And when I print the result before storing the bytes to a File, I am getting the following bytes values.

`255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 132, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 192, 0, 17, 8, 2, 37, 2, 47, 3, 1, 17, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, 255, 196, 1, 162, 0, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 125, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 17, 5, 18, 33, 49, 65, 6, 19, 81, 97, 7, 34, 113, 20, 50, 129, 145, 161, 8, 35, 66, 177, 193, 21, 82, 209, 240, 36, 51, 98, 114, 130, 9, 10, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 99, 100, 101, 102, 10`

Answer (score 4):

As Suggested by Antonin you need to load the file path.
use this to store your bytes in a temp file and then load the file

```
final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final filepath = "abc.png";
File imgFile = File(filepath);
imgFile.writeAsBytes(bytes); //your image bytes
```

and now use the file

Comment: I don't have a file path. All I have is the bytes as a result(Please check my question above). Now I need to convert the bytes to file. Please help me to convert the bytes to file. So that I can upload the file to the Firestore.

Comment: I have given the example of creating the file. filepath can be set to anything. that is the name in which file will be created

Comment: Okay, will try to implement the code! What is the use of this "final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();" Also I am getting this error - "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'abc.png' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607002/flutter-unable-to-create-directory-os-error-read-only-file-system

Comment: Yes.. as said by Eric, please use path provider plugin

Comment: fetch the image URL of the uploaded image and display

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue with the help of Ganesh Bhat.

```
  _originalImage = ui.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
  ui.drawString(_originalImage, ui.arial_48, 250, 340, 'Hello World');
    // Store the watermarked image to a File
   wmImage = ui.encodeJpg(_originalImage);
   Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path; 
   filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/abc.jpg';
   File imgFile = File(filePath);
   imgFile.writeAsBytes(wmImage);
   print(imgFile);
   imageFile = imgFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have an uninitialized object (null) on which *path* method is being executed which results in error. Check if all your *filesystem* objects are properly initialized by debugging or logging them out to a console.

Try checking `wmImage` and `Uint8List.fromList(wmImage)` what they're pointing to - my guess is one of those entities have *null* assigned.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get a file from a path but you give it bytes, you need to either load the correct path or convert bytes to a file

Comment: So how do I convert bytes to a file